# google calendar api (php) & the GitHub files missing

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Why google calendar api is not updated properly and the GitHub also not having the proper google-api-php-client (something is missing). They are just changing the code and not upgrade it properly. users struggle to find their apis and that too old versions - they make it complicated.

Is there any place that we can find a proper working example in php and is there a latest version of (without any bugs) GitHub google-api-php-client (no missing folders or files) ?

Waste of time by searching one by one.

Thanks

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/) contains the most up-to-date official samples.   Your question is unclear as to what exactly it is that you think is wrong.  Please edit your question and include your code and describe what issues you are having.